# Which database to use for iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, database

I'm working on a mobile app where i have to store the data of the user and when the app is closed and reopened the data is displayed automatically. I was wondering which db is ideal to start with for a novice when it comes to iOS and Android for something like storing high scores in game development?

Comment: There are a number of options... If you are looking to host the data remotely, I'd recommend MySql or Microsoft SQL. If you want to host on device then use SQLite

Comment: Why do you think you need a database just to track a few user scores?

Answer (score 5):

SQLite is supported in both Android and iOS.

Answer (score 3):

For ios use core data and for Android use SQlite.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/).

Its an embedded File-based SQL Databases that is used in iOS Coredata and could also be used in Android.
For examples [developers.android.com docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)

Answer (score 2):

For iOS there is a built in data mode called Core Data that is fully supported for what you are looking to do. There are a lot of documentation and tutorials available, here is a start in the right direction:

> http://www.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial

As for Android, SQLite is a comparable and certainly standard platform:

> http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Answer (score 2):

**Important for iOs**, do not use NSUserDefaults, it is editable (hackable) and it will ruin your users experience with GameCenter, since soon or later mean users will hack it and set maximum value, you can see it in many games, where in game center they all have ridiculous amounts of points.

SQLite is a good option, but it is also hackable/editable, since almost allways it stores data in a file with a text like syntax.

I recommend anything that could be encrypted.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to store one or a few scores you could put them in the iOS Keychain.

More that that save the data in an encrypted file with the encryption key in the Keychain, a good choice for encryption is [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor) which is available for several languages and platforms, it does all the necessary security wrapping.

If you need a database there are a few versions of SQLite that offer encryption.

Another option would be to compute a hash on saving, save the hash in the keychain and on reading again compute the hash and compare to the hash from the Keychain. If the hashes do not match the score has been manipulated.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a cloud platform like [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) or [Parse](https://parse.com/)? It handles all the heavy lifting for your data storage; setup is pretty simple and they're both well documented.

Answer (score -1):

If you only want to store the most recent high score then Core Data is an overkill on iOS, I would suggest storing a value like the high score in NSUserDefaults.

I'm sure there is a similar option for Android development.

Comment: Similar option is SharedPreferences. Simple key/value store perfect for a scenario such as this

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog NSUserDefaults is hackable, i do not recommend it for such task.